# Assembly - Carry flag - 0xFF

Tags: assembly, x86

In the next code:

```
mov ebx, 0xFF
add ebx, 1
```

Why the Carry flag is not set?

```
ebx = 11111111
+   = 00000001
     100000000
```

Comment: try bh or bl, 8 bit registers instead of a 32 bit register.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because `ebx` is a 32-bit register. It's large enough to hold the value (256) - hence no carryout.

A better test would be:

```
mov ebx, 0xFFFFFFFF
add ebx, 1
```

Comment: Ho, shame on me! I will accept it in 12 minutes (Stackoverflow's restriction)